# How to prioritize loading of image returned in a multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I have a function where it calls AJAX request in a loop. Because each AJAX request differs in API that will be used. Each AJAX request return html content that appends in the current html container and it also loads the images there. Since I've called AJAX in a loop it stacked up in the queue of HTTP requests so before the image load successfully it waits all AJAX request to be done just like this;

[image]

How can I show the images return by each AJAX once each call is successful?

So far, I've tried lazy loading but it didn't work.

Comment: `I have a function where it calls AJAX request in a loop` That's the root cause of your problem. Making AJAX requests in a loop is an anti-pattern as it congests servers, and also uses up the connections the client has available to the server. The latter point there is the reason your images are late to load; they need to wait for a connection to become available. To fix the problem change your code to make a single AJAX request with all data in it, then process a single response.

Comment: I see. I'm doing this because each AJAX call differ in API, and some API takes time to return a response that's why I wanted to return other API response that is available so user can see the response while waiting for the other API responses. Can you recommend any alternative on how to achieve this?